# CentOS7の正規表現の仕様は何に基づきますか？

Tags: linux, 正規表現

**CentOS7の正規表現仕様について**
・何に基づきますか？
・POSIX拡張正規表現？
・どうやったら確認出来ますか？

---

**なぜこの事を調べる必要ができたか**
・異なるOSやプログラミング言語及びソフトウェアで正規表現を使用することがあるのですが、「正規表現の違い」が「ある」のか「ない」のか、が分かりません
・それぞれ何に基づきどう違うのか知りたく質問しました

**この疑問が解決することで何を達成したいのか**
・正規表現の流れを知りたい
・独自の正規表現なのか、あるいは他と共通の正規表現なのか
・正規表現の用語についても、他と共通の正規表現用語なのか、仕様ではどう書かれているか確認したい

Comment: 思いついた疑問をすべて書くより、「なぜこの事を調べる必要ができたか」「この疑問が解決することで何を達成したいのか」を書いたほうが適切な回答を得やすいと思います。疑問が多すぎると回答を書く労力が大きいです。

Comment: 扱うコマンドやプログラミング言語によってどの標準に従うかが異なるのではないでしょうか。  [正規表現 -Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE#%E6%A8%99%E6%BA%96)

Comment: int32_tさんの内容と被りますが、質問者様は、よくこの形式で質問を投稿されておりますが、基本的に1問1答で収まるように質問したほうが良いかと思います。回答の労力もそうですが、疑問を持って質問を開いた方が情報を拾いにくくなります。複数の質問は都度質問を作成するといいです。

Comment: 関連？: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4882111/4506703

Comment: 「なぜこの事を調べる必要ができたか」と「この疑問が解決することで何を達成したいのか」を追記しました

Comment: 「この疑問が解決することで何を達成したいのか」があることで質問の趣旨が不明瞭になっているように感じます。

Comment: 「このOSだから××」の様には決まっていなくて、先にも述べた通りコマンドや言語によって実装が異なります。`man regex`で表示されるのはglibcのヘッダファイルに関する説明です。`grep`や`sed`など正規表現を扱うコマンドは大抵`man`で調べれば「正規表現」のセクションに説明があります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

正規表現エンジンは多数あり、POSIX拡張正規表現はエンジンの１つに過ぎません。`grep`、`sed`、`perl`、`JavaScript`等、各環境が独自に選定しています。「CentOSだから何々エンジン」と定まるわけではありません。
ですので、正規表現を導入している環境毎にどのようなエンジンを採用しているかを調べる必要があります。
[詳説 正規表現](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873113593/)を一読されることをお勧めします。

Answer (score 1):

環境・コマンド・プログラミング言語毎に正規表現の違いがあるので、どういう文法かなどはそれぞれ調べる必要があります。

POSIXで規定している正規表現は、標準ライブラリのものだけです。OSの一部として配布されているコマンドは標準ライブラリの正規表現エンジンを使っているかもしれません。そうではないかもしれません。また、標準ライブラリの正規表現エンジンでもOSによって挙動の違いがあります。ですので、POSIXの企画書を見てもほぼ意味がありません。

Java, perl, python, ruby, node などは標準ライブラリの正規表現エンジンは使っていません。さまざまな環境で同一の動作をしないと困るからです。